# Drag and drop a file in HTML/CSS using a little bit of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I am trying to make a drag and drop file which can be used to choose a file too but my problem is that what I have done for now i supposed to let me choose a file but it isn't. I am posting this so I can get some help and look if there are any errors in the code.

```
css part

body {
    background-color: #242424   ;
}


h1 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#custom-button {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #009578;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #custom-button:hover {
    background-color: #00b28f;
  }

  #custom-text {
    margin-left: 10;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #aaa;
  }
```

javascript and html part
https://pastebin.com/LVx6A7Sp

Comment: See https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js/  or https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your relevant JS and HTML code segments (not a link, and not all of your code  -- just minimal code to demonstrate your problem).  Also, you should be able to locate "errors" yourself either via the console or from your own debugging.  You should be able to **tell us** at what point in your code you aren't getting the result you expect, instead of asking us to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a console error because of following lines of your code.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
```

When you remove these two lines, your code works as expected.